# User-based keyboard key remapping

Tags: windows, keyboard, keyboard-layout

Is it possible to remap keys in Windows, but not for the whole computer, but only for the particular user. 
I'm aware about the "Scancode Map" key in the HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Keyboard Layout and some sites mentios a similar for HKEY_CURRENT_USER. But I tried, the latter doesn't work in Windows 7.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This would also be possible in AutoHotKey, its pretty easy to map keys to another key, you could create this script which would run when a user logs in, once the AutoHotKey script is closed (User logs out, or terminate from the System Tray) then it will stop mapping the keys instantly.

I think remapping is as simple as A::B and I think there is a tutorial on the AHK website:
http://www.autohotkey.com/

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion:

- Set up the key remapping that you want for the user,
- Export the registry key you mentioned above as, say, user1.reg
- Create a Logon script for the user that will import user1.reg
- For users that don't need key remapping, create a Logon script to delete the registry key